# Make the button with command automatically

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to make a GUI by using Tkinter, the program will analyze some files and then automatically list a list of items with button that when I click to it, it will run some specific function. But now every script I made will end up only run the function of the last item be listed. For example, my aim for the script below is the program will list button with number 0 to 14, when I click to it, it will print on console the number on that button. But by somehow it always print number 14, which the last button be listed.

```
from tkinter import *
r = []
for x in range(0,15):
    r.append(x)
def show(x = int()):
    print(r[x])

root = Tk()
for x in range(0,15):
    Button(root, text = str(x), command = lambda:show(x)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you intend do with `show(x = int())`? It is a weird way to write `show(x=0)` or if you are looking for type hints `show(x: int)`

Comment: @CoolCloud Yes, that's what I want. Thank you very much. Also I want x to be integer value so I write x = int()

Comment: This does not mean `x` will always be an integer, it can be something else depending upon what you pass